# Python | copy file from shared folder to local folder

Tags: python-3.x

I want to copy the content of a shared folder to local folder.
Issue is I want to use a specific user to acsses the shared folder, meaning i want to provide username and password for the copy method to use.
When doing like so, i get an permission error because the copy uses my user.

```
import shutil

source = "C:\\Users\\asafs\\Documents\\Test\\test.txt"
target = "C:\\Temp"

shutil.copy(source, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your program tries to use your user permissions is because you started it. You would have to start the process as another user.

## On Linux

```sh
su -s /bin/bash -u <user> -c <command>
```

## On Windows

```
runas /noprofile /user:<user> <command>
```

Neither require a password due to the `/bin/bash` and `/noprofile` switches, but on windows there is a way to change that without directly disabling the process at least. Neither are anything to do with python because python simply cannot do what you ask of it here, and any libraries that do it are likely to use a similar solution to what I have written here.

This is because when you start your python program you are starting python as your own user, so it can only do things you can do. You have to start it as a different user to make it do things as that user.

Hope that helps.